# How to build a system with two multicore microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, communication, freertos, multicore

I am thinking about building a system that utilizes two microcontrollers that communicate with one another. Currently, I am looking into using two stm32 microcontrollers. They have two cores and I will be utilizing both cores. Both MCs would have some processes with different priorities that would have to be run with different frequencies so I am thinking about running FreeRTOS on each microcontroller. Currently, I have divided my processes in such a way that only one core on both MCs would have to communicate with the other core. This means that an entire loop (simplified) of the system would go as follows: MC1.core1 -> MC1.core2 -> MC1.core1 -> MC2.core1 -> MC2.core2 - > MC2.core1 -> MC1.core1.

For the communication between MC1.core1 and MC2.core1 I am thinking of using the UART protocol over a serial bus. For the communication between both cores on each MC, I am thinking about using FreeRTOS.

Now my question is, does this sounds like the proper way to do things? In short, my requirements are 2 MCs with two cores each that have to execute some processes sequentially with hard time requirements.

Should I rethink my system architecture? Should I think about using different protocols and firmware? Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We don't know what the device must do so we can't know how to implement it best. Who knows if one single core MCU would handle it just fine.

Comment: Is each core essentially idle while it's waiting for the other cores to do things? If so, what's the point of having multiple harware cores? Also, UART protocol is probably the slowest protocol you could pick for chip-to-chip communication. You'd have to describe the nature and volume of data flowing between the chips in order to evaluate whether this is suitable for your application.

Comment: @Justme Basically the system would be controlling a drone. So we will be running control loops, data filtering, and transmission of data to a remote machine on the ground. I realize this might potentially be doable with a single MC but I also wanted to get the learning experience so my team and I wanted to at least consider using two MC.

Comment: Microcontroller is abbreviated as MCU.

Comment: @DaveTweed The other cores will not be idle, two processes will always be running concurrently on each core. If we have processes a and b on core1 and processes c and d on core2, they would be running in doubles (so a and c at once and after that b and d). The biggest amount of data that we would want to send is 9 floating point values with 100Hz frequency. Those would be acceleration, velocity, and orientation measurements. Could UART handle that and if not what other alternatives should we look into?

Comment: @Rodo Thank you. :)